# Using Oracle data in a SQL Server function

Tags: sql-server-2005, oracle10g, user-defined-functions

This one is doing my head in...

I need to retrieve data from Oracle and use it in a SQL Server view, stored proc or (preferably) scalar function.

The first part is to create a stored proc to retrieve data from Oracle

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCCStatus]
@Param1 nvarchar(10),
@Param2 nvarchar(10)
AS

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @sql_str nvarchar (300)
SET @sql_str = 'select count(*) from openquery(myOracleDB,' + char(39) + 'SELECT      Field1, Field2 FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 = '+char(39)+char(39) + @Param1+ char(39) + char(39) + ' AND PERSON = '+char(39)+char(39)+ @Param2 +char(39)+char(39)+char(39)+')'
 EXEC (@sql_str)

 END
```

Executing the above sp works fine.

How do I consume this in a view?
Alternatively how do I convert this to a scalar valued function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView
AS
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(myOracleDB, 'SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM Table1')
```

That is, include the columns you will later filter on.

Then you can create a scalar function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnCCStatus
  @Param1 nvarchar(10),
  @Param2 nvarchar(10)
AS BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM MyView
          WHERE Field1 = @Param1
            AND Field2 = @Param2);
END;
```

---

**EDIT**

Because you insist on having parameters included in OPENQUERY...

- A view cannot be parametrised.
- A function would have to employ `INSERT EXEC` which is not allowed (not in a function).

So it seems like you'll have to continue using the stored procedure approach.

It could be enhanced, though. You could add an output parameter to return the result of the dynamic query as a scalar value. That way you would be able to use the SP in a script. (But, again, not in a function. You would be allowed as much as *create* a function that attempts to obtain the result through the output parameter, but *running* it would fail with this message: `Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.`)

Here's how your stored procedure could look like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCCStatus]
@Param1 nvarchar(10),
@Param2 nvarchar(10),
@Count int OUTPUT
AS

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @sql_str nvarchar (300);
DECLARE @result TABLE (cnt int);
SET @sql_str = 'select count(*) from openquery(myOracleDB,' + char(39)
             + 'SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 = '
             + char(39) + char(39) + @Param1 + char(39) + char(39) + ' AND PERSON = '
             + char(39) + char(39) + @Param2 + char(39) + char(39) + char(39) + ')'
INSERT INTO @result
EXEC (@sql_str);
SELECT @Count = cnt FROM @result;

END
```

When using it in a script you would need a variable to return the result to:

```
...
DECLARE @QueryResult int;
EXECUTE @Param1Value, @Param2Value, @QueryResult OUT;
...
```

The `OUT` (or `OUTPUT`) keyword should be supplied for it to work correctly.

Comment: An elegant solution but not what I need.  The parameters MUST be included in the OPENQUERY else a time-out occurs.

Comment: @Morgan Matthews: Updated my answer.